# Grails installation on Virtual Machine Ubuntu

Tags: grails, virtual-machine

I've installed Ubuntu on my VM and I've got a problem with Grails installation. I've installed JDK, Groovy and downloaded package with Grails. I've added path for java, Groovy and Grails in files /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.profile.

When I run command 'grails' it gives an error "no command grails found". How can I check what is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without further info, just sanity-check `$PATH`, directory locations (using the `bin` dir?), etc.--the typical path-oriented stuff.

Comment: fyi - you don't need to install Groovy to use Grails; Grails comes with the version that it needs. You only need Groovy available if you're doing non-Grails Groovy work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dave hinted the answer in a comment but explicitly the answer is to add $GRAILS_HOME/bin to your PATH in the ~/.profile file.  $GRAILS_HOME should of course be replaced with the actual location of the Grails installation.

You may also need to `chmod +x $GRAILS_HOME\bin\grails`.